# Transitive dependencies not being pulled in build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I have 2 separate projects:

- core

  - api

Core contains all the dependencies, it is compiled and published locally using `sbt clean assembly publishLocal` (using sbt-assembly plugin to build a fatjar). api then adds core as a dependency in build.sbt.

Problem is - none of the dependencies declared in core's build.sbt seem to be getting added to api - i get `ClassNotFound` errors until I add each dependency individually to `api`

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you share your `build.sbt`. - BTW, one does not use **sbt-assembly** with libraries, just with final projects.

Comment: I need to be able to deploy `core` as a stand-alone project as well sometimes, hence using `sbt-assembly`.

Comment: Which build.sbt should I share, `core` or `api`? @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: It would be good if you can share both. - obviously after removing any sensitive information.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a Multi-Module Project make sure that `api` depends on core:

```
lazy val api = project.in(file("./api"))
  .settings(api.settings)
  .settings(api.dependencies)
  .dependsOn(core)
```

See here for more information: [SBT Multi-Project](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html)

If not you need a dependency in the `api` Project, like:

```
libraryDependencies +=  "com.mycompany" % "myproject-core" % "2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Make sure the path, name and version are correct. Check the output from `sbt publishLocal`. It should look like:

```
[info]  published myproject-core_2.12 to /Users/YOU/.ivy2/local/com/mycompany/myproject-core_2.12/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/jars/myproject-core_2.12.jar
```

Make sure to restart `SBT`, and that the `api` project with its dependencies is loaded correctly.

Also not that `Test` dependencies are not inherited.

Comment: I'm already declaring it in libraryDependencies as your 2nd example but it isn't working so I feel like I need the first one - could you explain what you mean by multi-module though?

Comment: I adjusted my answer. I also added some hints for the case that `api` is a separate project. Check them before you redo your setup.

Comment: So if I'm adding `core` to `api`'s libraryDependencies (like your 2nd example), is the expected behavior that `core`'s dependencies should be added to `api`'s classpath?

Comment: yes that must be the case, exceptions are if you exclue a dependency or if it is a test dependency